# mdmonitor service issue in linux

Tags: linux, services, centos-6

`chkconfig`  showing the output as `mdmonitor` service is running

```
[root@localhost ~]# chkconfig --list | grep -i mdmonitor
mdmonitor       0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

But `service` command showing the status as `mdmonitor` is stopped

```
[root@localhost ~]# service mdmonitor status
mdmonitor is stopped
```

service mdmonitor start command showing nothing

```
[root@localhost ~]# service mdmonitor start
[root@localhost ~]# 
[root@localhost ~]# service mdmonitor status
mdmonitor is stopped
```

In GUI (System > Administrator > Services ) showing as
[image]
[image]

my doubt is
In runlevel 5 `mdmonitor` is running but why **service** command showing the output as `mdmonitor` is stopped

```
[root@localhost ~]# chkconfig --list | grep -i mdmonitor
mdmonitor       0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

**service**

```
[root@localhost ~]# service mdmonitor status
mdmonitor is stopped
```

After reboot also same effect. what is the reason here?

I am using CentOS 6.2

Comment: what do logs say about this? Probably in `/var/log/messages` or some specific file in `/var/log`.

Comment: @gertvdijk /var/log/messages showing nothing about mdmonitor

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the reason for this issue.

Reason is `mdadm.conf` file, path of the file is `/etc/mdadm.conf`

This is the content of that file

```
# mdadm.conf written out by anaconda
MAILADDR root
AUTO +imsm +1.x -all
```

`mdadm.conf` file was not there under `/etc`, first I thought that by mistake someone deleted this file, later I come to know that none of the system (CentOs 6.2) contains this file, I checked other system also for confirmation, file was not there. (I think it's a bug, but I am not sure about this)
so copied this file from `CentOs 6.3` to `CentOs 6.2` and restarted the service and now it's working fine.

```
[root@localhost ~]# service mdmonitor status
mdmonitor is stopped
[root@localhost ~]# service mdmonitor start
Starting mdmonitor:                                        [  OK  ]
[root@localhost ~]# service mdmonitor status
mdmonitor (pid  3712) is running...
```